# Help with proof of closedness of a set

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces

Let $u_n$ be a sequence in Hilbert space such that $\|u_n\|=1$ for all $n$, and $\langle u_n|u_m\rangle=0$ whenever $n\neq m$.
Why is the following set closed: $\{0\}\cup \{u_n \mid n\geq 1\}$?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\| u_n-u_m\|=\sqrt{2}$.

So for any two points $x$, $y$ of your set $S=\{0\}\cup\{u_n; n\ge 1\}$ you have
$$x\ne y \Rightarrow \|x-y\|\ge1.$$

Hence every point of $S$ is an [isolated point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point).

If $x_n$ is a convergent sequence of points from $S$, then $x_n$ must be eventually constant. (Otherwise it would not be Cauchy.) So it converges to some point of $S$.

Comment: Excellent. I was going to write more or less the same. I'll have to become faster!